# Root directory of eclipse plugin project

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an RCP application based on eclipse plugins. I have a file and I want to put it inside the root directory of my plugin and access it from there, so it is  available on any platform (windows or linux). For example, my plugin name is **Test** and I have a file **TestFile.eap**

Currently I am using it form desktop

```
 private String  EapName = "C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\TestFile.eap";
```

I want to put TestFile.eap inside the root directory of Test and access it from there like:

```
File f  = new File(EapName);
```

How can I get the root of my eclipse plugin?

Thanks!

Comment: So you are going to include this file as part of your plugin?

Comment: yes I want to include it as part of my plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("your plugin id");

URL pluginURL = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("TestFile.eap"), null);

URL fileURL = FileLocator.toFileURL(pluginURL);

File file = new File(fileURL.getPath());
```

If your plugin is packaged as a jar (as they usually are) this will extract the file from the jar to a temporary location so that you can access it using File APIs.

Be sure to include the file in the plugin `build.properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

1) The file is static and deployed as part of your plugin:

```
URL url = new URL("platform:/plugin/my.plugin.id/the/relative/path");
InputStream inputStream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
```

2) The file is created on the fly and you need a place to put it:

```
IPath pluginStatePath = MyPlugin.getDefault().getStateLocation();
IPath filePath = pluginStatePath.append("my/relative/filepath");
```

For more information on both approaches, see [Where do plugins store their state?](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_do_plug-ins_store_their_state%3F)